# Lightbox gallery, text blocking form the popup

Tags: javascript, php, lightgallery

I used lightgallery for my photo albums. The problem is when clicking the photo the popup opens but it is trying to get the tagged text in the photo album. How can i block it ?

```
<div class="lightgallery">

           <a href="<?php echo HTTP_RESIM.'products/'.$product['image']; ?>">
           <img src="<?php echo HTTP_RESIM.'products/'.$product['image']; ?>" ></a>
          <h5><?php echo $product['name']; ?></h5>


        <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM product_image WHERE product_id = '".$product['id']."' AND status = '1' ORDER BY sort_order";
            $productImages = mysql_query($query);
            while($productImage = mysql_fetch_array($productImages)){
            ?>
                <a href="<?php echo HTTP_RESIM.'product_image/'.$productImage['image']; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo HTTP_RESIM.'product_image/'.$productImage['image']; ?>" >
            </a>
            <?php
            }
        ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".lightgallery").lightGallery(); 
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Is there any way to add some code or something for blocking <h5> tag in the popup gallery ?